# PHP/MySQL - Where to reliably handle insert auto re-request (locked table) - client or server?

Tags: php, mysql

I have function like so and want to automatically handle inserts on failed attempt (depending on reason for error) - it must be a lock condition.

This is an application for businesses so I am not relying on heavy traffic between client server, but still need to reliably handle inserts.

Where should I be putting the auto re-commit logic (api request, or in the actual php code) and how do I implement it?

```
public function createOne($params = [])
{    
    $sql = "insert
            into actionitems(
                    actionitemid,
                    assignorid,
                    ownerid,
                    altownerid,
                    duedate,
                    ecd,
                    criticality,
                    actionitemtitle,
                    actionitemstatement,
                    closurecriteria
            )
            values(
                    :actionitemid
                    :assignorid,
                    :ownerid,
                    :altownerid,
                    :duedate,
                    :ecd,
                    :criticality,
                    :actionitemtitle,
                    :actionitemstatement,
                    :closurecriteria
            )";
    try
    {      
          $this->db->beginTransaction();
          $this->db->setAttribute(\PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, \PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
          $locksql = $this->db->query("lock tables actionitem write");
          $statement = $this->db->prepare($sql); 
          $statement->execute([
                ':actionitemid' => $params['actionitemid'],
                ':assignorid' => $params['assignor'],
                ':ownerid' =>  $params['owner'],
                ':altownerid' => $params['altowner'],
                ':duedate' => $params['duedate'],
                ':ecd' => $params['ecd'],      
                ':criticality' => $params['criticality'],
                ':actionitemtitle' => $params['actionitemtitle'],
                ':actionitemstatement' => $params['actionitemstatement'],
                ':closurecriteria' => $params['closurecriteria'],
          ]); 
          return json_encode(['Result' => 'Success'], JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
          $this->db->commit();
    }
    catch (PDOExcetption $e)
    {
         $this->db->rollBack();
         return json_encode(['Result' => 'Action Item Was Not Created ' , 'Message' => $e->getMessage(0)]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Retry in a loop?

Comment: Yes, that was my first thought but I want to detect if the table failure occurred only on lock and, the main portion of my question was to determine where to perform this (client or server)?

Comment: Mysql locking related errors are technical problems that the client cannot really do much about. I would retry a couple of times in the server code before discarding the insert and sending an error back to the client.

Comment: I wouldn't care why it failed. Just retry (in PHP) a couple of times. If it fails on last try, return the error message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do something like this in PHP:

```
public function createOne($params = [])
{    
    // this should be set right after connecting - not here
    $this->db->setAttribute(\PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, \PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

    $sql = "insert into actionitems ... ";
    $statement = $this->db->prepare($sql);

    for ($attempts = 10; $attempts > 0; --$attempts) {
        try {
            $this->db->beginTransaction();
                $this->db->exec("lock tables actionitem write");
                $statement->execute($params);
            $this->db->commit();
            return json_encode(['Result' => 'Success'], JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
        } catch (PDOExcetption $e) {
            $this->db->rollBack();
            if ($attempts == 1) { // this is the last attempt
                return json_encode(['Result' => 'Action Item Was Not Created ' , 'Message' => $e->getMessage(0)]);
            } else {
                // do nothing and retry
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Notes:**

As I wrote in my comment - I would't care why it fails (since it should be a very rare case) and just catch the exception and retry.

I don't know why you lock the table for a simple insert. I keep it in the answer as it is, but I don't know why a simple insert should fail. At least on InnoDB it shouldn't or it would fail on any attempt.

I would also suggest to use a third party library. For example with Laravel's Database library it could look like this:

```
public function createOne($params = [])
{
    $attempts = 10;
    try {
        $this->db->transaction(function () use ($params) {
            $this->db->statement("lock tables actionitem write");
            $this->db->table('actionitems')->insert($params);
        }, $attempts);
        return json_encode(['Result' => 'Success'], JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        return json_encode(['Result' => 'Action Item Was Not Created ' , 'Message' => $e->getMessage(0)]);
    }
}
```

Less code usually lead to less bugs.

If you don't want to use a third party library, you can also write that function yourself (eg. in a trait). You can look at how they do it in laravel [here](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.8/src/Illuminate/Database/Concerns/ManagesTransactions.php#L20).

Comment: Re: Why I want to lock table?:  I want to use a surrogate key ActionItemID, instead of exposing my primary key ID my application.   How do I reliably use a sequential value and avoid a race condition on insert (low probability)?

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand. Do you mean `ActionItemID` is UNIQUE and `$params['actionitemid']` is kind of a UID?

Comment: I have an `ID` column, auto increment, primary key, but I don't want to expose it (unsure if this is necessary), instead I want another sequential value (`ActionItemID`) which I posted above, for my page to show.  ActionItem front end page should show an increasing integer instead of an arbitrary string like UUID or GUID.

Comment: I would just use the (AUTO_INCREMENT) ID. I don't know a good reason for a custom implementation of what is actually the same. However - usually you would get the next  `ActionItemID` with `select coalesce(max(ActionItemID), 0)+1 from actionitems`. This should be within the transaction in the try block. Then use the result instead of `$params['actionitemid']`. It might fail due to duplicate key, but then you retry and get a new number in the next step.